# Operations between temporal discrete intervals

Tags: discrete-mathematics, natural-numbers

I am going to present you my problem and ask you for solutions' references.

I have a discrete temporal series, which is the sequence of Natural numbers $T = \lbrace 1, 2, \dots, N \rbrace$.

An *Event* is a set of interval, where each interval is a couple $<start, stop>$. E.g, we can have the following *Event*:
$$E=\{ <0, 10>, <20, 30>, <40,50> \}$$

I want to define some operations between *Events*: $\cap,\cup,\setminus$ and explore their properties.

Do you know if I can find any references to solutions which can be applied to this problem?

Comment: Please clarify, how is this different from all subsets of $T$?

Comment: Thank you vadim. If I got your point, you suggest to consider $E_1$ as a subset of $T$, therefor if I need to interset it with $E_2$, that is the usual sets intersection. That is for sure the best and simplest solution, but someonewant me to formalize the problem as if the domain is the set of couples $TT = \{<x,y> : x,y \in T \}$.